# aws-iam-authenticator - syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I was setting up AWS CLI on **Linux** VM to connect with EKS (Kubernetes Server) and followed easy steps mentioned in the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-aws-iam-authenticator.html

Though all the steps were executed successfully but on verifying at the end, it throws

> Error: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

[image]

Comment: I don't think the curl command worked. Can you share the contents of, say, `head $(which aws-iam-authenticator)`?

Comment: Thankyou!! so much for your suggestion, It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em,aws-iam-authenticator size should be 17.7M.

```
curl -o aws-iam-authenticator https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.14.6/2019-08-22/bin/linux/amd64/aws-iam-authenticator
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 17.7M  100 17.7M    0     0  6789k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 6788k
```

What I see(you typed the command manually?) is that you are using the wrong url: 
https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.16.4/... instead of https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.14.6/

The output of you aws-iam-authenticator right now is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>1.16.4/2019-08-22/bin/linux/amd64/aws-iam-authenticator</Key><RequestId>........</RequestId><HostId>..........=</HostId></Error>
```

Use below:

```
curl -o aws-iam-authenticator https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.14.6/2019-08-22/bin/linux/amd64/aws-iam-authenticator
```

Comment: Thankyou!! so much, yes that was a problem. It worked.

Comment: The official [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/install-aws-iam-authenticator.html) seem to use the wrong URL - which lead me here. Thanks